# Install on Ubuntu 16.04 fails

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello-

I'm trying to install `ros-desktop-full` and have tried several times ending in the same error. There are dependency problems reported as `--configure` fails for several sub-components. Here is the first encountered:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-desktop-full
```

.....OK so far...numerous packages downloaded and installed...

```
Setting up ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs (0.2.0-0xenial-20161026-182630-0700) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions:
 ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions depends on libpcl-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-dev is not configured yet.
 ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions depends on libpcl1.7; however:
  Package libpcl1.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

....etc.

Then a string of similar failures where `--configure` fails

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252757/install-on-ubuntu-16.04-fails/) by [thealy](https://answers.ros.org/users/29145/thealy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to be mixing debian upstream packages `ros-desktop-full` with OSRF hosted packages `ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs` It is not recommended to mix those.

http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1